# Implementing "and" for Python class?

Tags: python, class, hook, logical-operators

I have code similar to this:

```
import operator
class Comparator:
     def __init__(self,fieldName,compareToValue,my_operator):
         self.op = my_operator
         self.field = fieldName
         self.comparedTo = compareToValue
     def __call__(self,row):
         my_row_val = getattr(row,self.field)
         return self.op(my_row_val,self.comparedTo)


class Row:
    class RowItem:
         def __init__(self,name):
              self.name = name
         def __eq__(self,other):
             return Comparator(self.name,other,operator.eq)
    val1 = RowItem("val1")
    val2 = RowItem("val2")
    val3 = RowItem("val3")
    val4 = RowItem("val4")
    def __init__(self, val1, val2, val3, val4):
        self.val1 = val1
        self.val2 = val2
        self.val3 = val3
        self.val4 = val4
    def __str__(self):
        return str([self.val1,self.val2,self.val3,self.val4])
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)


class MyTable:
    def __init__(self,rows):
        self.rows = rows
    def filter(self,condition):
        for row in self.rows:
            if condition(row):
               yield row

rows = [Row(1,2,3,"hello"),Row(1,2,7,"cat"),Row(1,2,3,"hi"),Row(7,7,7,"foo")]
mytable = MyTable(rows)
```

I can successfully run filtering tests, for example:

```
print list(mytable.filter(Row.val3 == 7))
# prints [[1, 2, 7, 'cat'], [7, 7, 7, 'foo']]
print list(mytable.filter(Row.val2 == 2))
# prints [[1, 2, 3, 'hello'], [1, 2, 7, 'cat'], [1, 2, 3, 'hi']]
```

but when I try to use an `and` it does not work as I would like:

```
print list(mytable.filter((Row.val3 == 7) and (Row.val2 == 2)))
# this only evaluates the second condition, instead of both conditions, printing:
# [[1, 2, 3, 'hello'], [1, 2, 7, 'cat'], [1, 2, 3, 'hi']]
```

How can I get the and to work correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot hook into the `and` and `or` logical operators, because they [short-circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation); the left-hand expression is evaluated first and if the result of that expression determines the outcome, the right-hand expression is never evaluated even. The operation returns the value of the last expression evaluated.

In your case, the `(Row.val3 == 7) and (Row.val2 == 2)` expression evaluates `(Row.val3 == 7)` first, and as that returns an instance without any specific hooks to say otherwise, it is [considered a true value](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), so the result of the right-hand expression is then returned.

You *can* use [`&` and `|` (bitwise AND and OR) operators](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations) here, these delegate to the [`object.__and__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__and__) and [`object.__or__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__or__) hooks. This is what ORM libraries like SQLAlchemy do.

The corresponding `operator` functions are [`operator.and_`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.and_) and [`operator.or_`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.or_).

Comment: Thanks for the tip about bitwise AND and OR operators, that's exactly what I am going for, however I'm getting an error of `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'instance' and 'instance'` when I add the `__and__` hook to the `RowItem` object. I'm getting the same error when I try to add this to the `Row` object. Which object should get the `__and__` hook?

Comment: @mgoldwasser: you need to implement that on your `Comparator` class, not on `RowItem`; your `==` expressions return `Comparator` instances, and that's what the `&` operator is applied to.

Comment: I have tried to implement this as you mention, but I am still only seeing the second condition getting used https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mgoldwasser/0ccc1480e8115bf0e9d7/raw/7ca2436877e913fcf481edca42eddaeb60290fbb/and_comparison.py

Comment: @mgoldwasser: you are returning `and` still where you should be using `&` instead. The `__and__` hook should return a new comparator.

Comment: thanks - I hacked together something based on your  input. I had to modify the `__call__` function as well, I think there might be a more elegant solution, but this works:
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mgoldwasser/0ccc1480e8115bf0e9d7/raw/d1c2e65632a7f8efbb052bfcb95a42e916e51742/and_comparison.py

Comment: You could use `my_row_val = self.field(row) if callable(self.field) else getattr(row,self.field)` and do the same for `self.comparedTo`, then pass those two results to `self.op`. No need to call into `self.field.__call__` directly in any case.